# How can I stop 'bin' items from appearing when searching Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, search

Whenever I search for a particular message, the results throw up tens of seemingly related messages/part messages from what appears to be the "bin" folder.

1. What exactly is the bin folder (junk, spam...)?
2. How can I stop these messages from appearing in my searches (or anywhere else for that  matter)

Answer (score 1):

Per http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/ZHgilTVP7ts/bpIWgcLAzrUJ

> The Bin holds deleted messages, so it should not normally contain all of your received and sent mail. If it does, there is a problem. Apple Mail does not handle drafts on the server well, and leaves the fragments behind. To avoid that, change the setting in Apple Mail to save drafts locally, not on the Gmail server.